# setting up Python interpreter

Tags: python

I'm following a video tutorial (not available online) for installing Python and setting it up to use with Eclipse (text editor).   To configure Eclipse to use Python, he adds the Python interpreter. In his movie, the python interpreter is a file `python.exe`.

However, when I'm browsing through my folder in Python, I don't see a file named python.exe. This (see image) is what I have instead.

1) which of these files do I click on to install the interpreter? or have I done something wrong and the correct file isn't here?

Thanks for your help.

[image: My python folder]

Comment: It sounds like you are using a Windows tutorial on a Mac. The correct file will not end with ".exe". I would try "Python Launcher".

Comment: get what from? what are you referring to?

Comment: @Andrew Hare  thanks, I just didn't want to break anything. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: What operating system are you running on?  python.exe will exist on Windows systems but will just be called "python" on a unix-based system.

Comment: The... thing in your screenshot.

Comment: @Andrew Hare, Launcher is an invalid interpreter it said. But I got it figured out I think. Found it in usr/bin/local python 3.2

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams it was just a folder that I browsed to. Sorry I can't explain better. I'm a newbie.

Comment: The contents of the folder came from somewhere. Where did they come from?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams it's fixed now. don't worry. it was just a folder in my harddrive.

Comment: @Michael: Please do not **update** the question with "Problem Solved" and comments.  That is not the way Stack Overflow works.  Please provide your own answer as a proper answer with the solution you found.  Remove the "PROBLEM SOLVED" from the question and remove the comment.  Create a proper answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

The path for the Python .exe can be found in: `/usr/local/bin/pythonw`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was using a windows tutorial when I should have been using a tutorial for Mac, so that explains why I didn't have an .exe file. Launching the wizard didn't set up the interpreter. I had to navigate to another folder on my Mac.